# Можно ли в одном методе в качестве параметра объявить объекты разных классов?

Tags: java, коллекции

Я пишу метод, в котором входным параметром будет либо List, либо Map, и в зависимости от типа которого будет разная реализация.
Так как List и Map не имеют общего интерфейса, это можно сделать так:

```
private void checkCollection(Object ob) {
    if (ob instanceof List) {
        System.out.println("List!");
    } else if (ob instanceof Map) {
        System.out.println("Map!");
    }
}
```

Но тогда не очевидно, что за входной параметр должен быть. Можно, конечно, воспользоваться перегрузкой методов, но очень хочется сделать это в одном=)

Есть ли возможность в java как-то объявить, что входным параметром может быть только один из этих типов?

Comment: А что вы с коллекцией собираетесь делать внутри? По-моему перегрузка методов отлично подходит на эту роль

Comment: Если обработка `List` и `Map` кардинально разная, то это должно быть два разных, независимых метода

Comment: Дело в том, что указанный метод по моей задумке реализован в абстрактном классе. И в этом классе есть абстрактные методы (они же и будут в зависимости от типа параметра использованы в данном методе), которые будут имплементировать классы-наследники. Поэтому, как мне кажется, так было бы удобнее)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если логика обработки полностью различается, а возможных входных типов мало (например, 2, 3 или 4), перегрузка метода является оптимальным решением:

```
private <T> void checkCollection(List<T> list)
{
    System.out.println("List!");
}

private <K, V> void checkCollection(Map<K, V> map)
{
    System.out.println("Map!");
}
```

---

Если же хотя бы одно из условий не выполняется, а общего интерфейса у объектов нет, то можно написать свой интерфейс и обёртки над возможными типами:

```
private void checkCollection(IMyCollection collection)
{
    int elementsCount = collection.getElementsCount();
    collection.print(elementsCount * 2 + 10);
}

private interface IMyCollection
{
    int getElementsCount();

    void print(int value); //столь спорный метод - только для примера
}

private class MyListCollection<T> implements IMyCollection
{
    private final List<T> list;

    public MyListCollection(List<T> list)
    {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public int getElementsCount()
    {
        return list.size();
    }

    public void print(int value)
    {
        System.out.println("List! " + value);
    }
}

private class MyMapCollection<K, v> implements IMyCollection
{
    private final Map<K, v> map;

    public MyMapCollection(Map<K, v> map)
    {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public int getElementsCount()
    {
        return map.size();
    }

    public void print(int value)
    {
        System.out.println("Map! " + value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Классы абсолютно разные, поэтому не удастся задать ограничение через дженерики (на самом деле можно, если это интерфейсы, то сделать класс или интерфейс имплимитирующий данные интерфейсы).
В вашем предложенном варианте, нет ничего плохого. По сути это так называемый `pattern matching` который широко распространен